# Why can assembly instructions contain multiplications in the "lea" instruction?

Tags: assembly, x86, disassembly, machine-instruction

I am working on a very low level part of the application in which performance is critical.

While investigating the generated assembly, I noticed the following instruction:

```
lea eax,[edx*8+8]
```

I am used to seeing additions when using memory references (e.g. [edx+4]), but this is the first time I see a multiplication.

- Does this mean that the x86 processor can perform simple multiplications in the lea instruction?
- Does this multiplication have an impact on the number of cycles needed to execute the instruction?
- Is the multiplication limited to powers of 2 (I would assume this is the case)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Notice how it's a multiply by a power of two.

Comment: See also [What's the purpose of the LEA instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658294/whats-the-purpose-of-the-lea-instruction) for more general stuff about using it for things other than strictly address calculations.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To expand on my comment and to answer the rest of the question...

Yes, it's limited to powers of two. (2, 4, and 8 specifically) So no multiplier is needed since it's just a shift. The point of it is to quickly generate an address from an index variable and a pointer - where the datatype is a simple 2, 4, or 8 byte word. (Though it's often abused for other uses as well.)

As for the number of cycles that are needed: According to [Agner Fog's tables](http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf) it looks like the `lea` instruction is constant on some machines and variable on others.

On Sandy Bridge there's a 2-cycle penalty if it's "complex or rip relative". But it doesn't say what "complex" means... So we can only guess unless you do a benchmark.

Comment: Thanks.  Also liked the reference to Agner Fog (although the link in your answer doesnt' seem to be correct).

Comment: Oops, bad copy+paste. Fixed now.

Comment: @Mysticial - AFAIK, this is not `lea` specific. Check out my answer :)

Comment: Note that while technically the multiplication is by 1,2,4 or 8, if you also consider the base register you can get multiplication by other constants, e.g: `lea eax,[edx*4+edx]` is equivalent to a multiplication by 5. This is very useful for strength reduction, e.g: the compiler can generate some smart code for a multiply by 1000.

Comment: @ninjalj Yeah, I'm aware of that. I just hid it under the "often abused for other uses as well" phrase. I've also seen multi-byte NOPs done with `lea`. Though I mostly see it used for out-of-place arithmetic.

Comment: I think this needs be mentioned as well: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrel_shifter even the 3 bit shift (*8) is instantaneous.

Comment: Complex means 3 operands or a shift > 1.

Answer (score 9):

Actually, this is not something specific to the `lea` instruction.

This type of addressing is called [`Scaled Addressing Mode`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addressing_mode#Scaled). The multiplication is achieved by a bit shift, which is trivial:

[image: A Left Shift]

You could do 'scaled addressing' with a `mov` too, for example (note that this is not the same operation, the only similarity is the fact that `ebx*4` represents an address multiplication):

```
 mov edx, [esi+4*ebx]
```

(source: http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs216/guides/x86.html#memory)

For a more complete listing, see [this Intel document](http://www.intel.com/design/intarch/manuals/243191.htm). Table 2-3 shows that a scaling of 2, 4, or 8 is allowed. Nothing else.

Latency (in terms of number of cycles): I don't think this should be affected at all. A shift is a matter of connections, and selecting between three possible shifts is the matter of 1 multiplexer worth of delay.

Comment: That `mov`  gets the **contents** of the memory at the generated "address", while `lea` gets the **generated "address"**

Comment: @ninjalj - The point is *not* what the mov does, but the fact that 'scaled addressing' (i.e. pointer math involving multiplying a pointer by 2,4,8) is not specific to `lea`.

Comment: @ninjalj - And since it appears to me that it was the wording of that part of my answer which was somewhat vague, I have explained the `mov` somewhat better now. Thanks.

Comment: the multiplexer thing is called a barrel shifter I believe.

Answer (score 8):

To expand on your last question:

> Is the multiplication limited to powers of 2 (I would assume this is the case)?

Note that you get the result of `base + scale * index`, so while `scale` has to be 1, 2, 4 or 8 (the size of x86 integer datatypes), you can get the equivalent of a multiplication by some different constants by using the same register as `base` and `index`, e.g.:

```
lea eax, [eax*4 + eax]   ; multiply by 5
```

This is used by the compiler to do strength reduction, e.g: for a multiplication by 100, depending on compiler options (target CPU model, optimization options), you may get:

```
lea    (%edx,%edx,4),%eax   ; eax = orig_edx * 5
lea    (%eax,%eax,4),%eax   ; eax = eax * 5 = orig_edx * 25
shl    $0x2,%eax            ; eax = eax * 4 = orig_edx * 100
```

Comment: See this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120207/imul-or-shift-instruction for why you should leave strength reduction to the compiler.