# x86 Multiplication with 3: IMUL vs SHL + ADD

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, intel, micro-optimization

I developed a program in x86-64 assembly which needs to iterate many times through the same operation:

```
IMUL rdx, 3   # rdx is always different
```

However, I need to make the runtime faster, so I thought of an optimization for that specific line from above:

```
MOV rcx, rdx
SHL rdx, 1
ADD rdx, rcx
```

Now I ask you guys: would this modification improve the runtime of the program (less clocks), or should I stick with the `IMUL` command?

Comment: It doesn't work, `add rdx, rdx` just doubles `rdx` again instead of adding the original `rdx`, and `shl rdx, 2` multiplies by 4 already, but how about `lea rdx, [rdx + rdx * 2]`?

Comment: I have seen this solution many times using `lea`, but I didn't manage to fully understand it. Would it be possible to clarify it? Also, would it be and improvement in performance?

Comment: `lea` [evaluates the address and then stores that in the destination](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1658294/555045), it's not a memory access despite looking like one.

Comment: Thanks! I also updated the question, but I guess now that is even less optimal. I will take a look on the explanation.

Comment: Do you mean `IMUL rdx, rdx, 3`? There is no `IMUL` instruction with only one register and an immediate.

Comment: Indeed, there is. Take a look into the developer's manual:  https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiXoqu-icHjAhUB0qYKHf3jAV8QFjACegQIBhAB&usg=AOvVaw0bkRab9lEOtDV0i4iY5kyf  page 3-443

Comment: @AndreasAbel : You are correct there is no 2 operand form that takes an immediate but what many assemblers do is generate the 3 operand form from the 2 operands. So `imul rdx, 3` is encoded as `imul rdx,rdx, 3` (the instruction would be encoded as `48 6b d2 03`)

Comment: Are you trying to improve latency or throughput? Which microarchitecture are you targeting?

Comment: The latency is what I am trying to improve. I am working on Intel Architecture, 64bit

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Both are terrible compared to `lea rdx, [rdx + rdx*2]`**, using a scaled-index addressing mode to get a total of `*3`, which is why compilers will always use LEA if you ask them to compile a function like

`long foo(long x){ return x * 3; }`  (https://godbolt.org/z/6p4ynV)

---

LEA is a way to feed arbitrary numbers through x86 addressing modes *without* using the result for a load or store, just putting it in a register.  [Using LEA on values that aren't addresses / pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46597055/using-lea-on-values-that-arent-addresses-pointers/46597375#46597375)

---

On all modern x86 CPUs, LEA is a single uop.  **The only question is *how much* better it is than the alternatives.**  `imul` is also 1 uop, but mov+shl+add is 3 for the front-end.  (This is true across all mainstream and low-power Intel/AMD that are still relevant.  See https://agner.org/optimize/)  64-bit `imul` is extra slow on some older microarchitectures, like Bulldozer-family and Silvermont/Goldmont, or especially older Atom.

On AMD CPUs (Bulldozer/Ryzen), it has a scaled index so it's a "complex" LEA and has 2 cycle latency (vs. 3 for `imul` on Ryzen, or much worse on Bulldozer-family where 64-bit `imul` is slower and not fully pipelined).  On Ryzen this LEA still has 2-per-clock throughput.

**On Intel CPUs**, it only has 2 components (one `+`), so it's a "simple" LEA with **1 cycle latency and can run with 2-per-clock throughput.**  So about the same cost as one `shl` instruction, but runs on different ports.

(Or on Ice Lake, 4-per-clock since they added LEA units to the other 2 integer ALU ports.  So it's exactly as cheap as one `add` on Ice Lake.)

---

You'd only want `mov` ; `shl` ; `sub` or `add` when your multiplier was 2^n +- 1 for `n > 3`.  Then it is worth considering `imul` for a tradeoff between latency and front-end throughput cost.

By shifting the original register, even CPUs without `mov`-elimination (before IvyBridge and Ryzen) can run your mov/shl/add sequence with 2 cycle latency critical path length.

---

Also related: [C++ code for testing the Collatz conjecture faster than hand-written assembly - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40354978/c-code-for-testing-the-collatz-conjecture-faster-than-hand-written-assembly/40355466#40355466) has some details about a problem with `*3` vs. optimizing with LEA.

Other related:

- [Multiplication with constant - imul or shl-add-combination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40564004/multiplication-with-constant-imul-or-shl-add-combination)
- [x86_64: is IMUL faster than 2x SHL + 2x ADD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37925143/x86-64-is-imul-faster-than-2x-shl-2x-add)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! One more small question: In this project I also use the `IDIV` command, but for 2 reasons: to extract the number rounded to the smaller integer and to extract modulo with `rdx`. Are there any possible optimizations, or the command should be used as it is?

Comment: @CosminAprodu: Again, ask a compiler. 
 Yes, multiplicative inverses are *much* faster than `div`. 
 [Why does GCC use multiplication by a strange number in implementing integer division?](//stackoverflow.com/q/41183935).  Given the quotient, you have to multiply and subtract to get the remainder.  Look at compiler output to see how it's done (especially for signed integers where sign-handling is tricky).